# I cant debug a windows service

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, windows-services

I am having trouble debugging windows service.
The service is installed and running and i have attached a debugger to the process.

I have set several breakpoints but when the debugger is attached i get:

**The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.**

All the configuration has been set to Debug.

Can someone please point me to a possible solution?

Comment: Presumably you mean that your local VS configuration is set to debug, but how was the service originally built?  Are you using the same version of code and/or pdbs as the build that is on the server?

Comment: The service was build and installed in the past. But i have same version source as the version of installed service. I am not sure about the PDBS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably won't help the first person asking but maybe someone with a similar problem.
In my case I fixed it this way, When selecting "Attach to process" I clicked "Select...": [image]

Then chose "Automatically determine the type of code to debug": [image]

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason could be that the service was built with Release configuration and you want to debug it by attaching it in VS.

Since you have the same version of source code with the previous-built service, why don't you build the service program based on the source code and then test it?